# Is it possible to jail break a iphone without knowing passcode/touchid?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

If a hacker steals my phone and does not know my passcode/touch id.. will it be possible for him to jailbreak my device and access all my data? particularly data in keychain?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. Depending on the exploit you don't even need physical access to the phone.

You could have an iPhone with iOS 8.3 and use the LibTIFF Exploit in order to execute remote code.

Talking about this exploit, you could use a particular payload that installs the attackers malicious code onto your phone, which would then be persistent. From this point on the attacker could do or not do (depending on the subset of features of the payload) do different tasks with your phone, finally also making it possible to fully jailbreak it (which would need some specific payload).

However: a jailbreak works this way. There are exploits which gets then used to inject a specific payload into the codebase of iOS.

> will it be possible for him to jailbreak my device and access all my data?

Sort of.

> particularly data in keychain?

No.

Comment: How is this going to give access to encrypted data?

Comment: As for encrypted data - those are most likely safe. However, an attacker still has access to the filesystem when using a proper exploit.

Comment: This would require access ahead of time, the questions was whether it could be done by someone stealing his phone.

Comment: The question isn't limited to encrypted data. It also includes the question for encrypted data whichs answer would be `No`. However, an attacker can get access to a locked phone when having a valid exploit. Images and specific meta data are not encrypted. Like, you can SSH on your phone without knowing the passcode and has access to the unencrypted filesystem of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

If the hacker just wants to access the data, the main attack vector isn't to jailbreak your phone, it's to simply bypass the login screen. Passcode can be brute forced without lockout by using a "NAND mirroring attack." The touchID can be bypassed by capturing and reproducing your fingerprint.

Of course, remote jailbreak with 0 interaction is probably possible too, but significantly more difficult than the aforementioned methods.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible with recent iOS versions. All your stored data is heavily encrypted and this cannot be bypassed or broken with a jailbreak.

Read this doc for more info: https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

and this post for more info on the way it handles the encryption: [iPhone: Is my data secure if phone is locked?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/169340/iphone-is-my-data-secure-if-phone-is-locked/169343#169343)